# Contradiction between GeoLite2 database and GeoIP2 precision web service

Tags: geoip

I am using the GeoLite2 city-blocks and city-location free databases and found the following ip_addresses have same locid number of 223, however if I type these addresses to GeoIP2 precision web service it gives me 4 different location information. Should one locid number correspond to only one location? I am really confused?

12.234.227.170 (WI, US by GeoIP2)
69.174.58.60 (IL, US by GeoIP2)
71.216.182.245 (Bremerton, Washington by GeoIP2)
74.44.255.2 (Lakeville MN by GeoIP2)

Answer (score 3):

GeoLite2 and GeoIP2 Precision results will differ in many cases. GeoLite2 provides access to  free, less accurate data than is available in the GeoIP2 Precision Web Services. (Note: I work for MaxMind, the company that creates GeoLite2 and GeoIP2 products.)

Comment: How less accurate is it on a country level?

Comment: I second that Q, all I see advertised is "less" accurate. What does that mean % wise.