# GeoLite2 accuracy in “Country” level

Tags: geoip, geolite2

MAXMIND info shows that GeoLite2 is less accurate than GeoIP2 DB when "City" resolution is required.
If only “Country” resolution is required – is the accuracy of the two DB equivalent?

Thanks in advance,
Gil

Answer (score 0):

From MAXMIND [accuracy](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-database-accuracy) page and from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042426/contradiction-between-geolite2-database-and-geoip2-precision-web-service) in stackoverflow, we know that the GeoLite2 is less accurate than GeoIP2 in "city" level. There is no information regarding the country level.